# How can Spray be asynchronous when HTTP is not?

Tags: http, asynchronous, akka, spray

It is said on the [Spray site](http://spray.io/):

> spray is an open-source toolkit for building REST/HTTP-based integration layers on top of Scala and Akka. Being **asynchronous**, actor-based, fast, lightweight, modular and testable it's a great way to connect your Scala applications to the world.

That **asynchronous** part confuses me because HTTP is a synchronous protocol.

Can you explain how Spray can be asynchronous when HTTP is not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spray uses [Akka](http://akka.io) underneath the hood as well as [Futures](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.7/scala/futures.html).  It is asynchronous in the sense that incoming requests are handed off to Akka Actors which in turn route the request and eventually generate a response.

In overly simplified terms, a request comes into the request handling actor and is asynchronously handed off to another actor that can deal with routing.  The request handling actor is free to process additional requests without blocking to handle the response.  The routing actor can hand off to a specific route handler in the same fashion.  The actor with the finished response can send it.

Actors can have different types of [dispatchers](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.7/scala/dispatchers.html) that define how they interact with threads to process messages, but essentially, the goal is to write code that never or rarely blocks, which is what the folks working on Spray have done.

Comment: sure.  I have a slightly dated, but deeper explanation of Akka dispatchers here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637031/understanding-the-different-dispatchers-in-akka-2/9642597#9642597  Hope it helps...